# Eloquent filter relationship on property of master instance

Tags: laravel, eloquent, relationship, eager-loading

I have models for `user` and `product`, with a many-to-many relationship between them in the table `product_user`. The relationship is set up on my `User` class as

```
public function following()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Product::class)->withTimestamps();
}
```

Products have many `feed`s, and each feed has many `release`s.

`Users` have a timestamp `last_notified_at`. What I'm trying to do is return a list of products which have had a release since the user was last notified.

I've been trying to user eager loading and `filter`:

```
User::all()->filter(function($user){
    print_r($user->load('following')->where('following.id', 1));
});
```

but having problems with memory and accessing the data at both the 'top' (user) and nested deeper (release).

Comment: `User::with('following')->get()->filter()`, you should eager load the relationship and don't call `load()` in a Loop. But, you can do this with a simple query too; `User::whereHas('following', function(...))->get()`, and in the function query for `id` of 1. Although, I think you're missing some logic in your question, so I can't say for sure if that will work for you. But, either way, calling `::all()`, and looping and loading is going to eat your memory since that's an additional connection/query for every loop (N+1 query issue)

Comment: users has last_notified_at, which column in releases or feeds do you tie that too, in regards when a new product should be notified?